# Secure delete logs in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, security, logging, secure-erase

Securely erasing data from OS X is easy. But is there a way to securely erase all logfiles (including the system logs contained in some database) without actually messing the system up?

Answer (score 1):

Can't vouch as to whether this will muck up Mac OS X, but to securely delete the system logs, try this from command line:

```
sudo rm -P /var/log/*
```

(Mac OS X comes with the `-P` flag for `rm` which overwrites data 3 times - similar to `shred` IIRC)